# Difference between Pointer Datatypes C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C/C++ Programming and I'm still learning some differences between pointer datatypes. But I struggled with these one:

```
int *const x1;
const int *x2;
char *x3[3];
char (*x4)[3];
double* x5, x6;
```

I think the first one should be a integer variable that points to a constant memory address
And `x2` should be a integer Pointer which is const, right?

I don't know if thats right. So can anyone explain me the differences between them?

Comment: Note: that `int *a` is a pointer, `int a[2]` is also a pointer (array)  that pointes to 2 values. `int *a[2]` is a pointer to array. It may help you a bit to understand

Comment: @Hearner: `int a[2]` is **not** a pointer (although it may *decay* to a pointer in certain cases).

Comment: @Hearner `int *a[2]` is an array of pointers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What does UB stand for?

Comment: As mentioned: No, `x1` is a constant pointer to a non-constant integer. And `x2` is a non-constant pointer to a constant integer. And so on. For most cases, you can just read the declarations backwards. I think this is a basic feature of most good tutorials to these languages, but maybe your one missed it out...

Comment: _"Thanks in advice"_ That's a new one

Comment: @Cheiron I _think_ Sourav was indicating that trying to apply identical concepts to both languages is likely to result in mishaps - by subtly using the metaphor of how the postincrement is unsequenced and therefore, if one were literally trying to evaluate the result of dividing a variable named `C` by (itself postincremented), anything could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *const x1;  // const pointer to int
                // x1 is const pointer, so it cannot point to anything else (once initilized),
                // but what it points to can changed

const int *x2;  // pointer to const int
                // x2 can points to something else,
                // but what it points to cannot be changed

char *x3[3];    // array of three pointers to char
                // (array of pointers)

char (*x4)[3];  // pointer to array of three char
                // (single pointer)

double* x5, x6; // x5 is pointer to double, x6 is just a double
```

Comment: The last example should not be written like that. The `*` belongs to the variable name, thus the star should be with the name as for the other declarations.

Answer (score 2):

For problems such as this you can check with [cdecl](http://cdecl.org), e.g. for your third example:

```
char *x3[3];
```

[cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%2Ax3%5B3%5D) returns:

> declare x3 as array 3 of pointer to char

and for your fourth example:

```
char (*x4)[3];
```

[cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%28*x4%29%5B3%5D%3B) returns:

> declare x4 as pointer to array 3 of char

Comment: cdecl does not work with multiple declarations (e.g. `double* x5, x6;`).

Comment: @Holt: true - you would need to apply a little common sense to that one and not get caught out by the associativity of the `*` - I wasn't planning to do *all* the OP's homework for him though. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this website.
Did not know that there is such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

You read C declarators backwards. "int * const" is therefore a constant pointer to int (you can change the int, but not make the pointer point elsewhere after initialization); whereas "const int *" is a pointer to a constant int (change the pointer all you like, but not the int it's pointing to).

"The C declarator syntax is an experiment that failed." according to Bjarne Stroustrup.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int *const x1;
```

constant pointer to `int`, that means the pointer cannot be changed to point anything.

```
const int *x2;
```

pointer to `int` constants. Here the integer is constant, which means you cannot change the value.

```
char *x3[3];
```

array (of length 3) of pointers to `char`

```
char (*x4)[3];
```

pointer to an array (of length 3) of char

```
double* x5, x6;
```

`x5` is pointer to double, `x6` is just a `double` variable